# Почем curl парсит страницу через раз?

Tags: php, парсер, загрузка

Всем привет. У меня есть функция:

```
function parser($url,$proxyserver){
   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxyserver);
   $result = curl_exec($curl);
   if($result == false)
   {     
     echo "Error CURL: " . curl_error($curl);
     return false;
   }
   else
   {
     return $result;
   }
}
```

Парсю вот эту страницу
https://data.nowgoal5.com/3in1odds/2126567.html

Она то парсится, то выдает иероглифы. Причем вообще рэндомно. Может 3 раза подряд пропарситься потом 4 нет. Или 1 раз потом 3 нет и тд...
Как сделать чтобы она всегда с 1 раза парсилась? Может в curl есть какой-то метод дожидания загрузки? Или кто что скажет?
Заранее спасибо всем кто ответит!!!

Comment: Сохраните ответ с иероглифами' в текстовый файл, а потом поиграйтесь кодировками. Возможно, там просто ответ от прокси " я устала, я перегружена"

Comment: Пробовал добавлять куки - не помогло
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');

Comment: Прикрепите файл с "иероглифами". Уже интересно самому посмотреть что же Вам там приходит в качестве ответа...

Comment: дык сами пропарсите эту страничку. увидите что приходит...

Comment: Вот такое возвращает ���r�̶&x];b��'��]?-!1p�-��DڦlP�EٖO�pP$DB��IJΩ��~����~���~��舮�~���@a�2�$�����J ��oM�r�Z�����zqֺ�Z���a�����Y.����rvtTmUs??��/9p(�Z��xfͭɸ=<:�5�|>�{t�X,��d�;j};Z�g�a��7s�'��n����_��߹ ǳc̓@�Rq�ϡ�����q��s��N�S�v7gu�#�/3s�?y?2��z�����q�   и тд